# Host server bloating with numerous fake session files created in hundreds every minute on php(7.3) website

Tags: file, session, server

I'm experiencing an unusual problem with my php (7.3) website creating huge number of unwanted session files on server every minute (around 50 to 100 files) and i noticed all of them having a fixed size of 125K or 0K in cPanel's file manager, hitting iNode counts going uncontrolled into thousands in hours & hundred thousands+ in a day; where as my website really have a small traffic of less than 3K a day and google crawler on top it. I'm denying all bad bots in .htaccess.

I'm able to control situation with help of a cron command that executes every six hours cleaning all session files older than 12hours from /tmp, however this isn't an ideal solution as fake session files getting created great in number eating all my server resources like RAM, Processor & most importantly Storage getting bloated impacting overall site performance.

I opened many of such files to examine but found them not associated with any valid user as i add user id, name, email to session upon successful authentication. Even assuming a session created for every visitor (without acc/login), it shouldn't go beyond 3K on a day but sessions count going as high as 125.000+ just in a day. Couldn't figure out the glitch.

I've gone through relevant posts and made checks like adding IP & UserAgent to sessions to track suspecious server monitoring, bot crawling, overwhelming proxy activities, but with no luck! I can also confirm by watching their timestamps that there is no human or crawler activity taken place when they're being created. Can see files being created every single minute without any break throughout the day!!.

Didn't find any clue yet in order to figure out root cause behind this weird behavior and highly appreciate any sort of help to troubleshoot this! Unfortunately server team unable to help much but added clean-up cron. Pasting below content of example session files:

0K   Sized> `favourites|a:0:{}LAST_ACTIVITY|i:1608871384`
125K Sized> `favourites|a:0:{}LAST_ACTIVITY|i:1608871395;empcontact|s:0:"";encryptedToken|s:40:"b881239480a324f621948029c0c02dc45ab4262a";`
Valid Ex.File1> `favourites|a:0:{}LAST_ACTIVITY|i:1608870991;applicant_email|s:26:"raju.mallxxxxx@gmail.com";applicant_phone|s:11:"09701300000";applicant|1;applicant_name|s:4:Raju;`
Valid Ex.File2> `favourites|a:0:{}LAST_ACTIVITY|i:1608919741;applicant_email|s:26:"raju.mallxxxxx@gmail.com";applicant_phone|s:11:"09701300000";IP|s:13:"13.126.144.95";UA|s:92:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0 X-Middleton/1";applicant|N;applicant_name|N;`

Answer (score 0):

We found that the issue triggered following hosting server's PHP version change from 5.6 to 7.3. However we noticed unwanted overwhelming session files not created on PHP 7.0! It's same code base we tested against three versions. Posting this as it may help others facing similar issue due to PHP version changes.